# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Hi I'm new to react and redux, and i have the following problem, adding clientName property to Proposals array in mapStateToProps gives me the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined", I have tried many things and I really can't find a solution.

```
const ProposalsPage = ({ proposals, clients, loading, loadProposals,loadClients }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (proposals.length === 0) {
      loadProposals().catch((error) => {
        alert("loading proposals failed " + error);
      });
    }

    if (clients.length === 0) {
      loadClients().catch((error) => {
        alert("loading clients failed " + error);
      });
    }
  }, [proposals]);
...
...
...
};

ProposalsPage.propTypes = {
    proposals: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    clients: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    loadProposals: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    saveProposal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    loadClients: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    
    return {
      proposals:
        state.clients.length === 0
        ? [] 
        : state.proposals.map(proposal => {
          return {...proposal,
            clientName: state.clients.find(c => c.id === proposal.id).name
          };
        }),
      clients: state.clients,
      loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0,
    };
  }
  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadProposals,
    saveProposal,
    loadClients
  };
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProposalsPage);
```

Comment: Should try: state.clients.find(c => c.id === proposal.id)?.name || ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be happening on the line:

```
            clientName: state.clients.find(c => c.id === proposal.id).name
```

You are seeing an "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error because in this case, the result of doing `state.clients.find(c => c.id === proposal.id)` is returning `undefined` for some values.

This could be happening either because there isn't any instance of `clients` that matches the `find()` `proposal.id` criteria (just one that doesn't match, is enough for the error to be thrown), or either because the `state.clients` data has not yet been loaded on the `state` at the time you want to evaluate the `state.proposals` data.

One solution to this issue, would be checking first that there is the `clients` data, and then attempting to map it to the `proposals` data, or use an empty value as a fallback, such as `null` or `undefined`.

For example:

```js
    return {
      proposals:
        state.clients.length === 0
        ? [] 
        : state.proposals.map(proposal => {
          const proposalClient = state.clients.find(c => c.id === proposal.id)
          if(!proposalClient) {
            // not found, so we can't map the 'clientName' right now, keep the proposal as is
            return proposal
          }
          // client found, return proposal with clientName
          return { ...proposal, clientName: proposalClient.name };
        }),
      clients: state.clients,
      loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0,
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem, I had some test data, and indeed there are some cases that find (...) does not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code cannot find the client with the given proposal id.
Are you sure this line is correct?

```js
state.clients.find(c => c.id === proposal.id).name
```

I assume that `client.id` is not relevant to `proposal.id`.
What I think is something like `client.proposalId`:

```js
state.clients.find(c => c.proposalId === proposal.id).name
```